# Seeking gis data or geospatial wildfires

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am looking for information about data that has wildfires in the United States but I am interested more specifically in Colorado. Do not be confuse with the Forest Fires. How or where do I find the GIS or geospatial data ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wildfire Location Data: National Interagency Fire Center (NIFC) supplies the fire data to geomac
https://www.nifc.gov/fireInfo/nfn.htm

NIFC Statistics
https://www.nifc.gov/fireInfo/fireInfo_stats_totalFires.html

Office of Wildland Fire funds geomac
https://www.doi.gov/wildlandfire

Wildfire - Wildland Fire Information Federal Fire Occurrence Website
http://wildfire.cr.usgs.gov/firehistory/data.html

Daily Incident Map
http://activefiremaps.fs.fed.us/lg_fire2.php

InciWeb Incident Information System has a lot of fire data, but you can search by wildfire
http://inciweb.nwcg.gov/

GeoMAC - existing wildfire situation in continental US and Alaska
http://www.geomac.gov/

Boulder has wildfire parameters, boundaries and a few more like that, which aren't live fire data, but you may find useful:
http://www.bouldercounty.org/gov/data/pages/gisdldata.aspx

OpenColorado has two more sets from Boulder, not sure but I'm guessing there may be overlap there:
http://data.opencolorado.org/dataset?q=wildfire

Here's an old Denver wildfire .kml
http://extras.denverpost.com/media/maps/kml/2013/ColoradoWildfires2013BlackForestRoyalGorgeBigMeadows.kml

Virginia's Department of Forestry Wildland Fire, Incident and Suppression Resources, and Wildfire Risk Assessment for the state and regions:
http://www.dof.virginia.gov/gis/dwnload/index.htm

Virginia's Department of Forestry Wildland Fire Incidents Map
https://vdof.maps.arcgis.com/home/index.html

MODIS satelitte imagery via NASA
https://earthdata.nasa.gov/data/near-real-time-data/data/hazards-and-disasters/fires 
https://earthdata.nasa.gov/data/near-real-time-data/firms/active-fire-data
http://lance-modis.eosdis.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/imagery/firemaps.cgi

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you've already encountered both of these but just in case...

The Monitoring Trends in Burn Severity is a remote sensed product with spatial extent of wild fires:
http://www.mtbs.gov/nationalregional/intro.html

The USFS also has a dataset built from the Fire Program Analysis system:
http://www.fs.usda.gov/rds/archive/Product/RDS-2013-0009.3/